# Uniswap v3 liquidity events contract

Tags: nft, liquidity-provider, uniswapv3

I'm a researcher trying to scrape data pertaining to UniSwap v3 liquidity events (add/remove liquidity to the pool).

Do all add/remove liquidity events have to go through the `Uniswap V3: Positions NFT` contract (`0xc36442b4a4522e871399cd717abdd847ab11fe88`) or are there other possible scenarios?

Thanks!